# Submit to a new page and download a file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have code that allows users to create and edit records in a SQL database. This works fine. However, now I want it to output the SQL scripts for what is being done. I'm not sure how to do this. Here is my current code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="form-group">
            <strong>ID:</strong>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <p>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ID)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID)
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    using (var client = new XServiceClient())
    {
        X x = client.Find(id);
        if (x == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(x);
    }
}
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(X x)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (var client = new XServiceClient())
        {
            client.Edit(x);
            return Redirect("~/Home/Index");
        }
    }
    return View(x);
}
```

I'm thinking in my controller I could do something like this:

```
using (var client = new XServiceClient())
{
    var sessionID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
    var filename = String.Format("Session-{0}.sql", sessionID);
    var sqlString = "Update SQL String Stuff";
    File(System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sqlString), "text/plain", filename);
    client.Edit(x);
    return Redirect("~/Home/Index");
}
```

Most systems I have seen recommend a return on that File line. However, that won't work with the rest of the program.
How can I get my submit button to submit the data to the server and also download a file to the user?

Comment: This has been asked many times before in many different forms. The answer is *you can't*. You only get one bite at the response apple. Either you return a view or something like a redirect or you return a file. You can't do both.

Comment: I guess that would explain why finding an answer on how to do this is so hard. Well, I found a way to get the basic task done. Thank you for your help.